# Not entirely sure on voting protocol/preferred question types

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Super User post: [Windows 10 will not install update](https://superuser.com/questions/1189370/windows-10-will-not-install-update)

Hi ya'll. Hate to be a pest and I'm sure "why was my question downvoted? *RAGE FACE*" queries are hideously frowned upon, with good reason, but I am genuinely a little confused by this one.

While the question is not exactly world changing, it seemed to me perfectly reasonable to want a version of Windows 10 with all the latest security updates, and if Windows fails to install them via the normal methods I'm not sure how I could be held at fault for not knowing where to manually download them without guidance (a Google search didn't seem to find this for me).

So, and at the risk of being a tad po-faced, can someone guide me on the legit reason for the downvote on this one, as I've been through the guidance on questions and I can't seem to find one as yet. But I'm sure I'm just overlooking something. Are there alternative ways of resolving this particular sort of question, for example, so would be preferable not to ask it here? Are there for example other sorts of question that the community would prefer I post, and this is being hinted at?

Comment: Your question was probably downvoted because [Tim Post lost his keys again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/349538).

Comment: To the wheel of blame!

Comment: @RailsKiddie I provided a reason for the vote, nothing, has been done about my feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with it personally. There's a few less than obvious things the question needed, that the comments caught, the answer is less than obvious and so on.

Sadly, the only person who knows is the downvoter, and they've chosen to be anonymous.